# Could not find class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnJava$JavaVersion]

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

i use intellij and java 1.8 for running my springboot

i have tried to create main jar like this on my code :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    private DemoMetricReaderWriter demoMetricReaderWriter = new DemoMetricReaderWriter();

    @Bean
    @ExportMetricReader
    @ExportMetricWriter
    DemoMetricReaderWriter getReader() {
        return demoMetricReaderWriter;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home() throws Exception {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // insert up to 2 second delay for a wider range of response times
        Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 2000));

        // let that delay become the gauge.bar metric value
        long barValue = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

        demoMetricReaderWriter.updateMetrics(barValue);
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

but when i build and run my jar i got error like this. and i have try to fix but i don't know what is exactly problem for this

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.example.demo.DemoApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnJava$JavaVersion]
```

this is my gradle.build for create this apps.

```
    plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.example.demo.DemoApplication'
    }
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    all {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
        exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-classic'
    }
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}

dependencies {
    // spring boot
    implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    }
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'

    // health check
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:1.5.14.RELEASE'

    // logging
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'
    implementation 'com.lmax:disruptor:3.4.2'

    // database
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:2.5.5'
    runtimeOnly 'com.oracle.ojdbc:ojdbc8'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'


    //datadog
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:1.5.14.RELEASE'


    // lombok
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'



    // testing
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.9.0'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

my question what is wrong on my code ? for run this code i use gradle i have tried use example from internet but still getting error.... how to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a dependency conflict with the module containing `ConditionalOnJava`. `ConditionalOnJava` is part of module `spring-boot-autoconfigure`. Let's see which version is selected by Gradle. To do so, we issue the following command:

```
gradlew -q dependencyInsight --dependency spring-boot-autoconfigure --configuration runtimeClasspath
```

The relevant output for us is

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:1.5.14.RELEASE -> 2.5.1
\--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:1.5.14.RELEASE
     \--- runtimeClasspath
```

This tells us that `spring-boot-actuator:1.5.14.RELEASE` depends on `spring-boot-autoconfigure:1.5.14.RELEASE`. `ConditionalOnJava` indeed contains a subclass `JavaVersion` in version `1.15.14.RELEASE` (`ConditionalOnJava$JavaVersion` part of the error message). However, Gradle also tells us that `spring-boot-actuator` is upgraded to `2.5.1` and that version doesn't contain the subclass `JavaVersion` anymore.

I'm afraid you need to upgrade Spring Boot Actuator to the version related to the Spring Boot version you're running:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
```

Sending actuator metrics to Datadog is available through [Micrometer](https://micrometer.io/) with starter [`io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-datadog`](https://start.spring.io/#!type=gradle-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.5.6&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=11&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=datadog), see [Actuator Metrics](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.6/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.metrics) documentation for details.

Comment: yup... i need to use the latest actuator.. but if i use latest actuator there is no package  ExportMetricReader
    ExportMetricWriter this annotation... and other my question is if i want to send http status log to datadog how to that ?

Comment: Datadog integration is now available through [Micrometer](https://micrometer.io/) with starter `io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-datadog`, see [Actuator Metrics](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.6/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.metrics) for details.